# Tailwind CSS: darkMode transition delays

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have darkMode toggling working with:

```
:root {
    --primary: var(--white);
}

.dark {
    --primary: var(--black);
}
```

However when I use:

```
* {
  @apply transition-colors duration-700;
}
```

the background colors of my divs will transition normally, but the colors of my text will be delayed by a second and it doesn't look good at all. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

EDIT: Here's an example of it happening: https://play.tailwindcss.com/DdPehHPHj1

Comment: Would you mind adding a snippet to your post? Have you tried using `transiton-all`? There could be a `delay` class on your text element, make sure it doesn't effect your color transition also

Comment: I tried to make one on play.tailwindcss.com, but they're not using v3 or JS enabled yet. I assure you my css has no trasition-delay though.

Comment: You can choose Tailwind version at the top right corner. About JS, you can write javascript along with HTML or write inline Javascript. Till there is a snippet, the problem would be more clear

Comment: I added an example to the question

Comment: I see the problem now. Using `transition` with `*` selector has caused this problem. Therefore, deeply nested elements will have longer delay since it takes longer for the `color transition` to reach deeper nested ones. To avoid this problem, only apply `transition` on which end-elements that has text node.

Comment: That didn't work: https://play.tailwindcss.com/oW7TV2KHa8?file=css

Comment: That's because you are applying `transition-color` on `body`, which is not the most child-element that contains text node. Remove `body` selector and try again

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, fixed it by explicitly adding text colors on all elements.

Before

```html
<p class="">Want to dig deeper into Tailwind?</p>
```

After

```html
<p class="text-black dark:text-white">Want to dig deeper into Tailwind?</p>
```

[Link to the fixed example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/zYUm66aJHE)